# G Suite Content Compliance using Regex to quarantine emails sent to 5 or more members

Tags: regex, security, gmail, google-workspace

I am a G Suite admin looking to set up a content compliance rule for gmail which quarantines any mail sent from the organization that has 5 or more recipients in its "To:" list.

When googling I found this article, https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934, and used the following regex `"To: ^[^@](?:@[^@]){5}"`, however, it seems incomplete and does not work.

Any G Suite admins or Regex pros who can lend me a helping hand? I would be most grateful. Thank you

Comment: This will match 5 times an @ sign after matching To where there has to be at least 1 char that is not an `@` before and after the matching the @ sign `To: (?:[^@]+@[^@]+){5}` https://regex101.com/r/Iza7Cv/1 What are the possible delimiters between the emails? Can you add an example string?

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: Yep it did! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could match `To:`  followed by repeating 5 times an `@` surrounded by at least 1+ any char except an `@` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
To: (?:[^@]+@[^@]+){5}
```

**Explanation**

- `To:`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^@]+` Match 1+ times any char except an `@`
  - `@[^@]+` Then match the `@` and again match 1+ times any char except an `@`
- `){5}` Close the group and repeat it 5 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iza7Cv/1)